# does string get automatically converted to float before comparision

Tags: python-3.x

Does Python convert automatically the second element to a float before comparing in the below script if not what needs to be changed?

```
from operator import itemgetter
data = [['A', '2', '4'], ['B', '2', '12'],
        ['C', '2', '88'], ['D', '2', '88']]

mx = max(data, key=itemgetter(2))[2]
print(mx)
mx_values = [d for d in data if d[2] == mx]
print(mx_values)
#[['C', '2', '88'], ['D', '2', '88']]
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: It does not convert it to float or int before it compares. You can check that by changing the value of C to `'088'`. It will NOT pick the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compares them as strings, you can define you own 'itemgetter' which does float conversion. But perhaps your numbers shouldn't be strings in the first place.

```py
def float_itemgetter(index):
    return lambda x: float(x[index])

data = [['A', '2', '4'], ['B', '2', '12'],
        ['C', '2', '88'], ['D', '2', '88']]

mx = max(data, key=float_itemgetter(2))[2]
print(mx)
mx_values = [d for d in data if d[2] == mx]
print(mx_values)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the value to int before you assign it back to mx, then you can compare integers. If you think your data will have floats, then its best to convert it to float and compare.

Here's how to do it.

```
from operator import itemgetter
data = [['A', '2', '4'], ['B', '2', '12'],
        ['C', '2', '088'], ['D', '2', '88']]

mx = int(max(data, key=itemgetter(2))[2]) #converted it to int
print(mx)
mx_values = [d for d in data if int(d[2]) == mx] #comparing with int
print(mx_values)
#[['C', '2', '88'], ['D', '2', '88']]
```

The output will be:

```
[['C', '2', '088'], ['D', '2', '88']]
```

Note that '088' and '88' both got matched to the max value of 88.